# Visual Studio Authentication of a project

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I made a mistake of not setting the correct authentication method when I created my API project in Visual Studio...
Is it possible to change the authentication of the project in Visual Studio after creation?

I have tried to find solution on the web but they aren't really helpful